# Add Prediction to Dygraph

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am following the tutorial from:

https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/

They show a prediction at the bottom and I want to add it to the original time series graph. So below is the code and I am not sure how to combine the two:

```
install.packages("dygraphs")
library(dygraphs)
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)

dygraph(ldeaths)
```

[image]

Then I made a prediction:

```
hw <- HoltWinters(ldeaths)
predicted <- predict(hw, n.ahead = 72, prediction.interval = TRUE)

dygraph(predicted, main = "Predicted Lung Deaths (UK)") %>%
  dyAxis("x", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dySeries(c("lwr", "fit", "upr"), label = "Deaths") %>%
  dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set1"))
```

[image]

How do I combine the two into one graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem this library requires you to combine the data and then add separate series "layers" to the plot. With your example you could do this:

```
# combine the time series actual and forcasted values
combined <- cbind(predicted, actual=ldeaths)

# plot the different values as different series    
dygraph(combined , main = "Predicted Lung Deaths (UK)") %>%
  dyAxis("x", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dySeries("actual", label = "actual") %>%
  dySeries(paste0("predicted.", c("lwr", "fit", "upr")), label = "Predicted") %>%
  dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set1"))
```

[image]

Comment: any chance you can change this to $ currency also?

Comment: On my system (Mac reading with Chrome) the axes, title and legend appear but no lines or areas .... all white background. My versions are up-todate per CRAN.

Comment: @42- I tested with `dygraphs_1.1.1.4` running R `3.3.1` on Windows with Chrome `56.0.2924.87` That's a screenshot from a fresh R session of the output so it definitely worked for me.

Comment: I wasn't doubting that you got the desire result. That's my upvote. Just letting others know that there might be unrecognized system dependencies. Also using Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)